# R data long to wide with multiple output columns/values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape2, spread

Struggling with how to word this so I'm not finding great results via search. Example input:

```
cust_id  make  part  price  color
1        jeep  wheel 10     gray
1        jeep  door  5      blue
1        jeep  seat  20     brown
2        ford  wheel 12     gray
2        ford  door  8      red
2        ford  seat  25     brown
```

Desired output:

```
cust_ID  make  wheel_price  wheel_color  door_price  door_color  seat_price  seat_color
1        jeep  10           gray         5           blue        20          brown
2        ford  12           gray         8           red         25          brown
```

Originally was using spread() but ran into issues with the string values. Switched to pivot_wider() but still not able to get multiple output columns/values for each unique part. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use pivot_wider:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = part, names_glue = "{part}_{.value}", values_from = c(price, color)) %>%
 dplyr::select(1, 2, sort(current_vars()))

  cust_id make  door_color door_price seat_color seat_price wheel_color wheel_price
    <int> <chr> <chr>           <int> <chr>           <int> <chr>             <int>
1       1 jeep  blue                5 brown              20 gray                 10
2       2 ford  red                 8 brown              25 gray                 12
```

Comment: Thanks! I meant pivot_wider, oops. Quick one- I'm getting an "argument not used" for names_glue. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SeanKelso I suppose you have the latest tidyr version installed. I used the data you supplied - if you use this on other data, the {part} has to be the same name as in "names_from = part" (so if ou take the names from another column this has to go in the "names_glue = " as well